# Create a dynamic object tree from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have these arrays

```
countryList = ["United Kingdom", "France", "Tajikstan"]

countryDetails = ["Markets", "Government", "Details"] 

countryFactors = ["Capital", "Labour", "Land"]

marketList = ["Primary", "Secondary", "Service"]

businessList = ["Businesses", "Info"]

supplyAndDemand = ["Supply", "Demand", "Price"]
```

I want these arrays to form an object as follows

```
Country.list ={
"United Kingdom":{
    "Markets":{ 
        "Primary":{
            "Businesses":{},
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
        "Secondary":{
            "Businesses":{},
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
        "Service":{
            "Businesses":{},
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
    },
    "Government":{

    },
    "Details":{
        "Capital":{
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
        "Labour":{
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
        "Land":{
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
    },  
},

"France":{
    "Markets":{ 
        "Primary":{
            "Businesses":{},
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
        "Secondary":{
            "Businesses":{},
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
        "Service":{
            "Businesses":{},
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
    },
    "Government":{

    },
    "Details":{
        "Capital":{
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
        "Labour":{
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
        "Land":{
            "Info":{
                "Suppy":0,
                "Demand":0,
                "Price":0,
            },
        },
    },  
  },
}
```

So basically depending on the name of the array, dictates what will follow after. So if the array name is "Markets" then underneath that array will be "marketList" array. etc

Does anyone have an idea? I was thinking of doing an if statement after the loop but the if statement has been modifying my code.

Here's an example of my code of what I've been doing: https://jsfiddle.net/4vcru3a0/

Comment: Regex's and case statements, inside nested `forEach`s, maybe...

Comment: either your question is not clear, or you are trying to automate a business logic which is not possible(which YOU have to program)

Comment: singsuyash, not sure why would you term this impossible. Reasons? Seems like a good question to me.

Comment: Contrary to your description, there's no obvious link between array entries and the lower-level array name. Markets -> marketList, Details -> countryFactors... There's no way to automate this as is, it's just going to be a number of nested loops.

Comment: Your code is working fine after a minor issue fixed. You just need to handle the case of Businesses, and Info following the same procedure. I see right output in console https://jsfiddle.net/zphwak0h/ . Am I missing something?

Comment: In the array "countryDetails", when it hits the value of "Details", the array "countryFactors" should nest underneath the object which is not happening.

Comment: Whoops I fixed the problem, in the if statement it should've been a double "==", I'm an idiot

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dynamic approach for any depth of nesting objects.

```js
function iter(object, i) {
    data[i].forEach(function (k) {
        if (i + 1 < data.length) {
            object[k] = {};
            iter(object[k], i + 1);
        } else {
            object[k] = 0;
        }
    });
}

var data = [["United Kingdom", "France", "Tajikstan"], ["Markets", "Government", "Details"], ["Capital", "Labour", "Land"], ["Primary", "Secondary", "Service"], ["Businesses", "Info"], ["Supply", "Demand", "Price"]],
    tree = {};

iter(tree, 0);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is fine if the structure is consistent but there are abnormalities in the structure which I'm looking to create (you can see the structure I'm looking for in the example I included in my question).

Comment: Whoops I fixed the problem, in the if statement it should've been a double "==", I'm an idiot